# Maven Assembly Plugin jar-with-dependencies -> No Dependencies in Jar

Tags: maven, jar

The following reference mentions the descriptor Reference jar-with-dependencies. Afaik it is a predefined assembly, which includes all jar dependencies into a single big self-contained jar file. This is great if you have multiple dependencies and need to copy your project to another machine because you don't need to update/delete obsolete libraries separately.
https://newfivefour.com/category_maven-assembly.html

I added the maven-assembly-plugin to my pom, and the MyTool.jar-with-dependency.jar is created. I expected that the jar contains all external dependencies, but it is the same as the normal MyTool.jar and does not contain any dependencies like apache.commons or apache.logging.

The important detail is that the dependencies scope is set to `provided`. Without this it works as expected. But I use the scope later on with the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all dependencies in the `provided` scope to a specific directory.

```
[...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>privided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>    
<build>
    <!--pluginManagement-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin> <!-- This is the plugin I added. -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                 </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
[...]
```

I use Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14).

How can I include the dependencies from the `provided` scope? Or is there an other solution?

Comment: Stop using [Maven 2 migrate](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) to Maven 3.*

Comment: Without the full pom file it is impossible to help...

Comment: Using maven 3 the build fails: `Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved [...] Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.` This is the only error I get.

Comment: First use a more uptodate version of maven-assembly-plugin...furthermore the error message shows that you might have a problem either with proxy/firewall or with the access to your repository manager ...which should be configured in your settings.xml...

Comment: I just found the detail that caused the problem. And I did not mention it before because I thought it was not important. I use the `provided` scope for my dependencies. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You need to use a different assembly descriptor. There you can define the scope ...